# Flutter dialogue wise access data

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have some problems with flutter dialog wise. For short, I don't understand how to use a headless CMS. I already read the documentation a few time.

I wanted to add content dynamically in my app using a headless CMS, I have my apiKey and emailHash. This is the code that I got from their website.

I don't understand how to get the content from the platform, when I run the code, I get all the text that I put in dialogue wise, but how can I acces just a part of it? And how I can add it in my flutter application? For the moment it displays just in the console, because I printed it, but I don't know how to put it in a widget.

```
Future<void> main() async {

  //Prepare the payload
  var request = new DialogueWiseRequest();
  request.slug = 'hero-section';
  request.apiKey = 'myapi';
  request.emailHash='/myemail';

// Call the Dialogue Wise API
  var dialogueWiseService = new DialogueWiseService(new HttpClient());
  Map res = await dialogueWiseService.getDialogue(request);

//Print the Output to Console
  print(res);

  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Content received:

```
{dialogue: [{dish-name: Orzo Veg Soup, dish-photo: https://media.dialoguewise.com/FabFoodsStore/orzo-veg-soup.jpg, is-available: true, long-description: <p>This delicious Orzo Veg Soup is packed full of flavor. Ingredients include:&nbsp;</p><ol><li>Carrots</li><li>Tomato</li><li>Celery</li><li>Vegetable stock</li></ol>, price: $6, short-description: Delicious Orzo Veg Soup}, {dish-name: Chicken Hot Dog, dish-photo: https://media.dialoguewise.com/FabFoodsStore/hotdog.jpg, is-available: true, long-description: <p>This delicious Chicken Hot Dog is packed full of flavor. Ingredients include:&nbsp;</p><ol><li>Chicken Sausage</li><li>Tomato</li><li>Lettuce</li><li>Mayo</li></ol>, price: $7, short-description: Chicken Hot Dog with Mayo.}], totalRecords: 2, error: }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi @Alexandru based on your post, what I understand is that you are already getting the response. So looks like the code is fine. If you want to display it, you will need to create a Flutter app with a widget and then load the contents in that widget. We've created a sample application on our [Github](https://github.com/dialoguewise/flutter-fab-foods-mobile-app) that you can check out. Please feel free to get back to us if you still have questions. Happy to help.